# How do you download a web application from Azure?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-storage

My company has been given a web application in Azure.  This is our first Azure project; typically we develop C#/asp.net apps in Visual Studio with data in SQL Server and move the finished app to a web server.

I've connected Visual Studio 2015 to the Azure account.  I can see the blobs, tables, and files.  I've found a few html templates, but don't see any controllers; I think they might be in .dll files in the bin folder.

I would like to download the entire web application to Visual Studio on my local machine so I can debug it, make changes, and then republish the site.  How do I do this?  I can double-click on the files and view them in VS and I suppose I could save them one at a time, but that doesn't seem efficient.  How can I download the whole project including putting the data in the blobs into something I can test locally (or connect a local VS instance to the remote data/blobs)?

Here is what I'm seeing from the Azure site in Visual Studio:

[image]

Update 1:

I think what I'm trying to find at this point is the js controllers (i.e. browseController.js).  I can't find any controllers on Azure.  Where would they be?  Here's the expanded Cloud Explorer:

[image]

Comment: I think there is a way to download the files. Not from VS but from the azure portal. I think it is one of the links on the Right hand side of your website's dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to download the entire web application to Visual Studio
>   on my local machine so I can debug it, make changes, and then
>   republish the site. How do I do this?

I don't think it is possible to do what you're trying to accomplish because what gets deployed is the compiled code and not the source code. You would need source code to make changes.

You can take a backup of the application that's currently running into blob storage and from there you can download the application but again it would be the compiled application and not the source code.

Comment: Thanks; this is all new to me.  Two questions for you:  (1.) How do I get the source code?  Our client says everything is in Azure; I don't think we're going to get any other code from them.  (2.) I see a .dll on Azure.  I've been told the site is in Angular JS.  As far as I know, js files aren't compiled.  Would the js files be in the .dll file though?

Comment: (1) You need to ask your client about how the project was developed. May be the source code is with the company who originally built the application. (2) The `js` file will not be in `.dll`. I would have imagined it go in `Scripts` folder but I don't see any in the screenshot you shared above. You really need to go back to your client and ask them about the source code.

Comment: Thanks so much; this is very helpful.  A couple of questions about the js controllers, I can't find any js controller files on the Azure side. I've updated my screenshot to show the expanded structure.  Where would these js files be on Azure and how do I get to them (since I can't seem to see them)?  If they're not on Azure how in the world is this site working?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about Angular. What I have done is edited your question and added Angularjs tag. Hopefully someone familiar with this will take a look and answer your queries. All the best!

Comment: Thanks for the help Gaurav!